# On checkout get specific currency

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

Just one more step to launch my magento store and I really need some help. 
My store has as base currency USD (really need it to be that way), and I'd set up as possible currencies: USD/ BRL/ EUR. (for view purposes)
When checking out I need to be charged in BRL. 
So, how do I make the system to get this currency on checkout? Do I have to change something in the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this:

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
```

This should get the currently set currency code.

So if you'd like to activate some sort of special text when currency code is EUR, then maybe you might want to try:

```
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

if ($currentCurrencyCode == 'EUR') {
   echo 'Je sens un européen';
}
elseif ($currentCurrencyCode == 'GBP') {
   echo 'Rule Britannia!';
}
```

Paste this code and use according to your requirements on checkout page.

Comment: Keshar, I apreciate your answer, however what I really need is to the magento system only recognize currency = BRL to checkout, even if the user is using USD or EUR in the view.

Comment: Hey guys... can anyone help?